# Non linear QM and wave function collapse

Tags: quantum-mechanics, specific-reference, measurements, wavefunction-collapse, non-linear-systems

I heard that there have been some propositions about describing the collapse of the wave-function by adding non-linear terms, but I couldn't anything in any any textbooks or even articles (probably those propositions never reached a good level of consistency). However, I'd like to read about it. Could someone send me a reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ghirardi-Rimini-Weber Model is such a theory.
See for instance http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406094.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, nonlinearities aren't compatible with Lorentz invariance. The overall probability renormalization factor also needs to be rescaled globally, although that might not be a problem if rejecting a probabilistic ontology.

Comment: Can you explain to us what is the probabilistic ontology and what is the issue of global rescaling?

Comment: Well, based on Weinberg proposition for non linear QM, the non linear observables need to be of order one in $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ so non linear operators in the Hamiltonian will be suppresed by factors $n = \int d^3x \;\psi(x)\psi^*(x)$ which is a non-local quantity.

Answer (score 2):

Roger Penrose advanced the notion that gravity causes wave function collapse, giving handwavy arguments involving the Schrodinger-Newton equation (one particular flavor of the nonlinear Schrodinger equation).

The references I'm aware of:

1. Roger Penrose, "On Gravity's Role in Quantum State Reduction", *General Relativity and Gravitation* **28** 5 (1996) 581-600. [DOI:10.1007/BF02105068](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02105068)
2. Roger Penrose, "Quantum computation, entanglement and state reduction", *Phil. Trans. R. Soc. Lond. A* **356** no. 1743 (1998) 1927-1939. [DOI:10.1098/rsta.1998.0256](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rsta.1998.0256)

Answer (score 1):

**Collapse of the State Vector**

Phys. Rev. A 85, 062116 (2012)

http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6462